# C#, .net, general programming architecture. GetType or Enum : Which is better?

Tags: c#, .net, types, enums

Which do you think is better..

```
        if (thing.GetType() == typeof(thisthing))
        {
           //do stuff for this type of thing.
        }
```

Or give the objects an Enum property

```
        if (thing.TypeName == NamesEnum.thisthing)
        {
           //do stuff for this type of thing.
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends:

```
if (thing.TypeName == NamesEnum.thisthing)
```

will run more performant then `GetType()` as, this a simple comparison of 2 numeric values.

But:

```
if (thing.GetType() == typeof(thisthing))
```

is more more "flexible": when you do some refactoring, change type name or whatever, this condition will still work.

But will fail in condition, if 2 types belong to 2 different assemblies, instead in first case this still will be matched as equal,as you campare not `types` but just enum values.

In short, there is no best approach, just *most suitable* for your needs.

Answer (score 12):

Neither of these is a particularly extensible or maintainable approach.

It's typically better to design this directly into a virtual method in your type hierarchy, and just call the method.  This allows other classes to override and provide custom functionality as appropriate.

In your case, the `thisthing` type (which should be named `ThisThing` if you want to follow .NET naming conventions) would just have a `DoStuff` method which could be virtual if needed, and call it.

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question, there are a lot of valid cases when virtual methods are just inapplicable.

Answer (score 3):

**IF** you are working with basic types that don't have sub types...
your first example can be shortened nicely to

```
if (thing is typeof(thisthing))
```

Depends on the situation really. If you get to a lot of different types you're going to want a switch statement at some point, so I would say option 2 if there are going to be a lot of types.

Comment: Note that this is actually not the same as the OP's check (though this is more likely a better alternative).  The `is` keyword will return true for subclasses as well as the actual class, where the OP's version requires the type to match exactly.

Comment: `is` will match subtypes too, not just exact type match.

Comment: Good point, I'm making the assumption that the types don't have subclasses

Comment: Did you mean `thing is thisthing`?